# Vision Kit - Extract Image Data in Dictionary - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, visionkit

I had scan the image using Vision Kit framework and I was able to extract data in string but I want it in key value pair such like dictionary( [String: Any] ).

```
private var ocrRequest = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: nil)

ocrRequest = VNRecognizeTextRequest { (request, error) in
guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else { return }

var ocrText = ""

for observation in observations {
    
    guard let topCandidate = observation.topCandidates(1).first else { return }
    ocrText += topCandidate.string + "\n"
}


DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.ocrTextView.text = ocrText
    self.scanButton.isEnabled = true
}
}
```

**Output of the Observation String:**

```
East Repair Inc.
Invoice #
US-001
Invoice Date
11/02/2019
P.O.#
2312/2019
Due Date
26/02/2019
```

and I need an output like:

```
{
  "marchantName": "East Repair Inc.",
  "invoiceNumber": "US-001",
  "invoiceDate": "11/02/2019"
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: A dictionary of what? A key value pair, but do you have an example of what values  (`observations`) you have, and what should look like the dictionary?

Comment: So your questions is more about transforming `[String]` into `[String: String]` where you know "the format/logic/order" behind the array. But could there be other order, or except for the name, the invoiceNumber will always have before "Invoice #", etc.?

Comment: The format will never be same always for all the Receipt so how would I can able to make a dynamic model for all the receipt?

if you have a demo/example then please share. Is there is any other way to extract data from image?

Comment: Not even the fact that `Invoice Date` will be before the date? If not, how are you supposed to make sense. It's like getting three random pages from 3 different book, and ask you to sort them by the book title. How are you supposed to know from which book it comes from?

Comment: So is there any way to get JSON from observations?